# One mimus Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude equals one

Tags: swift, math

For some reason if I do `1.0 - Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude` it returns `1.0`.

First question, why?

Second, how can I get the smallest `Double` that is bigger than zero and actually works when I do some math?

Ps.: The reason I'm looking for this is to avoid some NaNs I'm getting when multiplying the `sigmoid` derivative with a cross entropy loss derivative.

```
A) sigmoid: 1 / (1 + exp(-z))
B) sigmoid derivative: sigmoid * (1 - sigmoid) // s * (1 - s)
C) cross entropy loss derivative: -y / s + (1 - y) / (1 - s)

B * C = s - y
```

Multiplying `B` and `C` should give me an actual number, but I'm calculating `B`, then calculating `C`, then multiplying the two, which is giving me NaN in some cases (because of division by zero on `B`).

Ps.2: I do know that having `epsilon = 1e-16` and simply add that to my functions works, but I'm looking for something "more correct", if you know what I mean.

**EDIT:**

Explaining why this question is not a duplicate of the one mentioned, on this one I'm asking for the solution for an "epsilon" number, not why floating point math is broken. I don't care that much about the low level details, I just want a solution that is reliable in the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: To answer your second question - you already have the smallest `Double` that is bigger than zero :)

Comment: `1.0.nextDown` may be what you are looking for, it is the greatest representable Double value strictly less than `1.0`

Comment: @MartinR why does `nextDown` seems to work but `nextUp` doesn't?     `> 1.0 - 0.0.nextUp`
    `> Double = 1`
    `> 1.0 - (1.0.nextDown)`
    `> Double = 0.00000000000000011102230246251565`. The reason I'm asking this is because maybe `nextDown` is not so reliable, since `nextUp` isn't.

Comment: You probably mean  `1.0 - 1.0.nextUp` ?

Comment: No, I really meant `1.0 - 0.0.nextUp`. I'd expect it to be a little less than `1.0`

Comment: `0.0.nextUp` is the same as `Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude` and approx. 4.94e-324. `1.0 - 4.94e-324` is indistinguishable from `1.0` within the precision of a 64-bit float.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I edited my question to explain why this is not a duplicate. Also, about your other comment, that solution I mentioned is not reliable, in the future Swift might change that value (or depending on the operating system), that's what I meant with "more correct" solution.

Comment: What I meant that you always have `x.nextDown < x < x.nextUp`, so in your case `let eps = 1.0 - 1.0.nextDown` or `let eps = 1.0.nextUp - 1.0` instead of `let eps = Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude` *might* be what you need.

Comment: There is no fixed epsilon value in floating-point arithmetic - it's always relative.